# jpa mssql create datetime column with TemporalType.TIMESTAMP and portability

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, jpa, timestamp

I have an entity with a following column definition:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateStart;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateEnd;
```

In derby jpa automatically create TIMESTAMP columns. When I want to use the same application with Microsoft SQL Server, I have problem, because jpa automatically create column with TIMESTAMP type. In MSSQL only one TIMESTAMP column per table can exist and thus I have error in this situation. I can resolve the error by providing additional information about column definition:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
private Date dateStart;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
private Date dateEnd;
```

But this solution is not portable. Derby cannot create such datatype as DATETIME.

What is a best solution for portability in jpa and to achieve two (or more) columns with date+time values ?

Comment: Have you tried creating your table outside the java code, using sql scripts, in which case, the existing table type will be used.

Comment: Yes it would be a solution. I am just looking at automatic table creation with jpa/eclipselink with rdbms agnostics.